# Solidity IDE Parser Error on Token Name

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix, error, parser

Getting this in Solidity:

```
browser/ballot.sol:121:16: Parser Error: Expected Primary Expression.
```

Here is my code, says that it is the name line with the parser error

```
function ERC20Token(
    ) {
    balances[msg.sender] = 888888;               
    totalSupply = 88888888;                        
    name = “DoubleHappiness";                                
    decimals = 8;                           
    symbol = “DBL";                               
}
```

Comment: function ERC20Token(
        ) {
        balances[msg.sender] = 888888;               
        totalSupply = 88888888;                        
        name = “DoubleHappiness";                                
        decimals = 8;                           
        symbol = “DBL";                               
    }

Comment: The code you shared here has weird quote characters (`“` instead of `"`). Any chance that's the issue?

Comment: This usually happens when you copy and paste code from certain webpages - it's happened me before!

Answer (score 1):

There’s a different quotation mark opening the string assigned to name.

```
name = **“**DoubleHappiness";
```